# Does assembly assemble code from bottom to top?

Tags: assembly

I am confused, i have this simple hello world program, compiled and tested [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php).
How does assembler know what to write into `ecx`, even though the command `msg  db  'Hello, world!',0xa` is executed at the bottom? Does assembler read the code from bottom to top, or how does this work?

And another question. Why is there `0xa` behind `msg db 'Hello, world!`?

```
mov edx, len    ;message length
mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80        ;call kernel
mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80        ;call kernel

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa     ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
```

Comment: The assembler can emit a placeholder  and fill it in later when it figures out the address. Some assemblers also use multiple passes.  `0xa` is just the ascii code for a line feed.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand!

Comment: You can assemble then disassemble the object, then link it with something and dissemble that and you can see what the tools are doing.  sometimes they leave a placeholder that gets filled in, sometimes they replace the instruction with another/others.  the modifications are of course link specific, linked in another place or other project the linker may choose other solutions (near vs far externals in particular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembler just produces machine code out of Assembly code. The machine code then runs.

Answer (score -1):

0xa is the ascii value for end of line character.